# HTML Multi Select Submission into Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-sheets

I Have created a webpage that includes a login system (using PhpMyAdmin) and a questionnaire using html forms which is submitted into Google Sheets. I need this as I am importing the data into Excel by just using a refresh tab to automatically get all the records so I can use it to fill out a preexisting form on Excel.

In my HTML Form, I have included a multi select dropdown. This dropdown displays the different machines. My problem is that, on submission of the HTML form the data that is extracted into google sheets doesn't include all the selections only the first selection in the multi select question on the form.

I have tried using [] in the name tag on the select statement. But this wont add anything into google sheets.

Below is a JSfiddle displaying my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jlythgoe/3d0ore4x/5/

```
label id="machine-ordered">What Is the Machine(s) You Ordered?</label> <br>
                <select class="selectpicker" name="ordered-machine" data-width=98.5% data-size=6 multiple="multiple">
```

This is the video i used to connect a form to the google sheets:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB2g6-LlObQ&t=192s

The column that stores the multiple selections should look something like:
D400, D500DUO

What i am getting:
D400

Answer (score 0):

Comibine the selected options via another input field. By changing the Select elements 'name' into something else, and add a hidden input with the name 'ordered-machine', this means that the data sent to google sheets is now taken from the combined hidden input and not from the select.

```js
const multiSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="ordered-machine-select"]');
const multiOutput = document.querySelector('input[name="ordered-machine"]');

function handleMultiselectChange(event) {
  // get a list of the selected option values...
  const optionValues = Array.from(
    multiSelect.selectedOptions
  ).map(option => option.value);
  // join the selected values together, and put them in a text (or hidden) field
  multiOutput.value = optionValues.join(', ');
}

multiSelect.addEventListener('change', handleMultiselectChange);
```

Above is the code that would be placed before the  tag in the page where the selection is.